# how to cancel gitlab previous pipeline when new pipeline job is triggered

Tags: gitlab

I'm looking for mechanism to cancel previous pipeline job if an existing pipeline job is active and running and upgrade in a particular environment in GitLab. Thanks

When two services are modified one after another in quick succession, the helm job fails because it doesn't run two upgrades simultaneously.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Auto-cancel redundant pipelines

You can set pending or running pipelines to cancel automatically when a new pipeline runs on the same branch. You can enable this in the project settings:

On the top bar, select Main menu > Projects and find your project.

On the left sidebar, select Settings > CI/CD.
Expand General Pipelines.

Select the Auto-cancel redundant pipelines checkbox.

Select Save changes.

Use the **interruptible** keyword to indicate if a running job can be cancelled before it completes.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#auto-cancel-redundant-pipelines

```
stages:
  - stage1
  - stage2
  - stage3

step-1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - echo "Can be canceled."
  interruptible: true

step-2:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - echo "Can not be canceled."

step-3:
  stage: stage3
  script:
    - echo "Because step-2 can not be canceled, this step can never be canceled, even though it's set as interruptible."
  interruptible: true
```